# Saving a line field into a variable

Tags: awk

I am trying to make a simple script for which I need to keep a field in a variable. This is what I have:

```
BEGIN{
  FS=":";
}

{
    print;
    item=$1;
    print "    "$1;
    print "    "$2;
    print "  item:<"$item">";
}
```

What I don't understand is that when I pass the script a line, this is the output:

```
main.o: src/main.cpp src/CMenu.h src/CUtils.h src/CAbsPlayer.h \ //given line
    main.o                                                       //field 1   
     src/main.cpp src/CMenu.h src/CUtils.h src/CAbsPlayer.h \    //field 2
  item:<main.o: src/main.cpp src/CMenu.h src/CUtils.h src/CAbsPlayer.h \> //field1?!
```

why does this not work, why is the whole line saved to `item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
print "  item:<"$item">";
```

Should be:

```
print "  item:<"item">";
```

Awk can look a lot like C; there is no $ before a variable name.  In awk, $ indicates a field, so $item tries to use the value of item as an index into the record.  On my implementation of awk (Mac OS), your script as written fails fast; I guess your awk implementation is more permissive (but not in a helpful way in this case).

Comment: Oh. I see. I worked with awk only briefly, so I assumed it would work with variables as bash does. I am running Kubuntu, which doesn't tell me any warnings or errors. Thanks